# Custom file output name format using incremental letters instead of numbers?

Tags: customization, file-format

Lately I've been experimenting with importing rendered animation frames into a game engine which expects a very specific filename format consisting of four letters, followed by a fifth incremental letter, followed by a static numerical value.

```
NAMEA0.png
NAMEB0.png
NAMEC0.png
```

Is there a way to make it so blender automatically saves my rendered frames following this format? With frame 1 = A, frame 2 = B and so forth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would happen with more than 26 Frames?

Comment: Not natively as far as I know, but you could probably script it with python. Might just be easier to rename them using a third party tool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is awkward, I just figured it out. I had looked at an answer to a similar question here, but having no experience with scripting, I thought I wouldn't know how to adapt it to my needs. Turns out that after looking at some basic python tutorials, I managed to write a script that, while not very elegant, definitely works. Here's the script in question:

```py
import bpy
letter = 'A'
def handler_set_filepath_based_on_frame(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == 1:
        letter = 'A'
    if scene.frame_current == 2:
        letter = 'B'       
    if scene.frame_current == 3:
        letter = 'C'
    if scene.frame_current == 4:
        letter = 'D'               
    if scene.frame_current == 5:
        letter = 'E'
    if scene.frame_current == 6:
        letter = 'F'               
    if scene.frame_current == 7:
        letter = 'G'  
    if scene.frame_current == 8:
        letter = 'H'        
    if scene.frame_current == 9:
        letter = 'I'  
    if scene.frame_current == 10:
        letter = 'J'  
    scene.render.filepath = ("/tmp/NAME%s0#" % letter)


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(handler_set_filepath_based_on_frame)
```

I'll likely will never need to render more than 10 frames or so. So manually defining a variable for each isn't that much of a hassle.

Here's the answer from which I based my script off of.
[Changing filename format based on current animation frame?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61913/changing-filename-format-based-on-current-animation-frame)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import bpy

def handler_set_filepath_based_on_frame(scene):
    letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']
    scene.render.filepath = ("/tmp/NAME%s0#" % letters[scene.frame_current])
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(handler_set_filepath_based_on_frame)
```

then you don't have to care for each frame